# How to update $scope in Ionic slide box?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've changing a $scope variable dynamically but Ionic doens't detect the change:

In my controller:

```
$scope.something = "something" ;
```

And in my ion-box I see $scope.something, but when try to set a new value to $scope.something ionic slide box doesn't detect the change. If I do the new value has been set..

`console.log($scope.something) // The new value`

A lot of people says that with $ionicBoxDelegate.update() is enough but doesn't work me. I also tyied all options that I've seen on Internet, but there is no way.

My code works because if I move it to a normal view, out of a slide, runs fine. Using the same code with the same controller.

Is a mystery. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If the scope isn't updating correctly you can use `$scope.$apply()` to force angular to re-evaluate the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a codepen. Will this help?

http://codepen.io/nabinkumarn/pen/obVbmN

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="SlideBoxController as vm">
        <div style="height:30px">{{vm.something}}</div>
        <ion-slide-box show-pager="true" on-slide-changed="vm.onSlideChanged($index)">
          <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
            <div class="box">
              <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
              <p>{{item.desc}}</p>
            </div>
          </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
</div>
```

JS

```
vm.something=1
  vm.onSlideChanged = function(slideIndex) {
        vm.something ++;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see your code, in particular, how you are updating `$scope.something`.

I created the snippet below (loosely based on [Scott Whittaker's codepen](http://codepen.io/ScottWhittaker/pen/dPeepe)). Is this what you're trying to accomplish:

```js
    angular.module('app', ['ionic'])
    
    .controller('SlideBoxController', function($scope) {  
     
      $scope.something = "old value";
      
      $scope.items = 
        [{title: "item 1", desc: "item 1 description"}, 
         {title: "item 2", desc: "item 2 description"}
        ];
    
       $scope.onSlideChanged = function(slideIndex) {
         if (slideIndex === 1) {
             $scope.something = "new value";
         }
         else
         {
             $scope.something = "old value"
         }
       };
    })
```

```css
.slider {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.box {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
    <html ng-app="app">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">     
        <title>Ionic Slide Box</title>
        <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>    
      </head>
      <body>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-calm">
            <h2 class="title">Slide Box</h2>
        </ion-header-bar>  
        <ion-content scroll="false">
          <div ng-controller="SlideBoxController">
            <ion-slide-box show-pager="true" on-slide-changed="onSlideChanged($index)">
              <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in items">
                <div class="box">
                  <h3>$scope.something = {{something}}</h3>
                  <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
                  <p>{{item.desc}}</p>
                </div>
              </ion-slide>
            </ion-slide-box>    
          </div>
        </ion-content>  
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't want to change $scope on SlideChange, I have a search input and when I write a list appears whith words that match with the input text, when the user click on the <li> element, I want to update the input with the value of the <li>.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the model needs a dot. Because I was using it in a filter and and input.